# Trying to concatenate string with integer but unwanted values is getting added

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a Dataframe which has 2 columns, I am trying to create a new column `column3` with a logic of concatenating values of `column1` (String) and `column2` (int) with a separator ('_').

Below are the few initial values of the dataframe:

```
    column1  column2
  0  Andy     1
  1  Ashok    4
  2  Collins  7
```

Below are my few attempts :

```
df['column3'] = df['column1'].apply(lambda x: x + '_' + str(df['column2']))

df['column3'] = df['column1'] + '_' + str(df['column2'])

df['column3'] = pd.Series(df['column1']).str.cat(str(df['column2']), sep='_')
```

Below is the result:

```
0       Andy_0       2\n1       2\n2       1\n3     ...
1       Ashok_0       2\n1       2\n2       1\n3    ...
2       Collins_0       2\n1       2\n2       1\n3  ...
```

But (`2\n1       2\n2       1\n3     ...`) is getting added to the result column3 value and only one value zero(0) is getting appended to the result column3.

Please let me know where the things are getting wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to make it so complicated. dataframe support such operation:

```
df.column1 + "_" + df.column2.astype("str")
```

Answer (score 0):

You want this:

```
def concat_cols(row):
    return "{}_{}".format(row['column1'], row['column2'])

df['column3'] = df.apply(concat_cols, axis = 1)
```

The key aspect is `axis = 1`, which looks at the dataframe row-wise, rather than column-wise. In your code above, `df['column2']` in the lambda function was referring to the entire column, rather than just the row's value.